# Very Stuck on subroutines in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

I have been working on a problem for my computer architect class for 2 days now and have exhausted all my resources. I have read the text until words do not make sense anymore. I have tried and tried in my visual emulator (visUAL) but I just cannot understand this homework problem.

Write a function (subroutine) that inputs a data value in register r0 and returns value in r0. The function returns y = a 1 bx + cx^2, where a, b, and c are parameters built into the function (i.e., they are not passed to it). The subroutine also performs clipping. If the output is greater than a value d, it is constrained to d (clipped). The input in r0 is a positive binary value in the range 0 to 0xFF. Apart from r0, no other registers may be modified by this subroutine.

I wrote a little bit of code to try and even get on the right page, but I really have no idea if it is even some-what correct.

```
Func1 MOV r0, #X ;load r0 with input (X)
     MOV r1, #A
     MOV r2, #B
     MOV r3, #C
     MUL r0, [r0,R0] 
     MUL r0, [r0, r3]
     MUL r0  [r1, #1]
     MUL r0, [r0, r2]
```

This is just the start and as far as I've gotten. I think I'm wrong already because I see that I keep modifying r0. And I'm using more than r0 to do the problem which it clearly states not to.

Thank you for any help that could be provided!

Comment: Are you allowed to use the stack? Because if r0 is the only register you're allowed to  modify, what I would do is push r0 after you save a value, modify r0, pop it back off the stack when you need the original value.

Comment: I would start with pseudocode, then massage that into more primitive steps until they start to resemble and can be replaced by real instructions.  If you can only modify r0 then as answered above, you must preserve them on the stack.

Comment: "MUL r0, [r0, r2]" - what syntax is this? Grab a reference for your assembler for a start... The task makes little sense with its "a 1 bx", you probably misunderstood/misread something and just wasting your time now...

Comment: MUL is a syntax in my textbook for multiplication, so sorry if it’s not real. I’m really just following what my text says and the problem I was giving. Also, SO literally let’s you check a button for getting help on a homework problem. I’ve consulted tutors, and have asked my professor and peers and have received no help because they’re just as confused as me. Believe me, I didn’t want to come on SO to just get belittled for asking for help. I’m just trying to learn a complex subject so I can someday work on my own projects.

Comment: Nobody should belittle you!  Some people are a bit abrupt, but that isn't meant as belittling.   This is a helpful space.

Comment: It's not the `mul` mnemonic that's the problem, it's the operands you're giving it!  ARM is a load/store machine where only special instructions (like `ldr`) can load from memory.  Not a CISC where any instruction can take a memory operand.  And yeah, you should fix the formatting of your polynomial.  I assume it's supposed to be `a*1  +  b*x + c*x*x`.  You can evaluate it as `(x*c + b) * x + a` but I think that sill needs 2 registers (to hold the original `x`, and to hold constants if they can't fit in an immediate).  So you should save/restore another one to use as a temporary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARMv7 has no operations on memory other than load and store.  It isn't possible to perform the calculation you desire with only one register on it.  Perhaps the intent of the question is not that you can only use one register, but rather you can only modify one register.  In that case, you can save and restore other registers from the stack.

Your statement of the function has a typographic error in it: *y = a 1 bx + cx^2* must be *y = a + bx + cx^2*

Lets break your problem down in pseudo-C:

```
int f(int x) {
    return A + B*x + C*x*x;
}
```

Now, try re-writing it in a simplified, stack based C, where you can only operate on R0, but you can save and restore R0 in a few memory locations:

```
int f(int R0) {
    int stack[4];
    stack[0] = R0;  /* saved copy of parameter */
    R0 = R0 * R0;   /* x^2 */
    R0 = R0 * C;    /* oops can't do this; needs a register for C */
    stack[1] = R0;  /* cx^2 */
    R0 = stack[0];
    R0 = R0 * B;    /* oops, can't to this; needs a register for B */
    RO = A;
    R0 = R0 + stack[0];  /* oops, can't do this... */

    return R0;
}
```

So, we need another register.   Thankfully, arm has lots:

```
int f(int R0) {
    int stack[2] = {R1, R2};
    R1 = R0;
    R1 = R1 * R1;
    R2 = C;
    R1 = R1 * C;   /* R1 = cx^2 */
    R2 = B;
    R0 = R0 * R2;  /* R0 = bx */
    R0 = R0 + R1;  /* R0 = bx + cx^2 */
    R2  = C;
    R0 = R0 + R2;  /* R0 = a + bx + cx^2 */
    R1 = stack[0];
    R2 = stack[1];
    return R0;
}
```

Now, all that is left is to convert this into arm assembly.
stack[2] = { R1, R2}  -->   push {r1,r2}
{R1, R2}    = stack[] -->   pop {r1,r2}
....

Comment: And "The subroutine also performs clipping. If the output is greater than a value d, it is constrained to d (clipped). " needs a bit of extra code...

Comment: I just wanted to say thank you so much for all your help! This really explained it all! I also did reach out to the professor and he clarified the problem because it was not correct. The struggle of attending a cheap online college :(

Comment: You are very welcome.  In the real world, the problem statements are never right.  It may be an advantage to hone a level of skepticism early.   Good Luck.